# Backup with Déjà Dup failing

Tags: backup, deja-dup

New to Ubuntu, new to Déjà Dup too.
I have been trying to setup Déjà Dup to backup the typical sub-folders of Home/ (ie my personal and my wife's personal folders) while keeping out the backups of everything else that would be unnecessary. I keep getting this error message:

```
Permission denied when trying to create
‘/media/b154cec8-cffb-4653-ad8b-2dc4d4cc72d0/backup/duplicity-full.20131209T171550Z.vol1.difftar.gz’.
```

This happens despite that I added the folder /media on the ignore list.

Ignore list folder:

- Trash
- Downloads
- .gvfs
- smb://192.168.1.1/media/
- smb://rt-n16/media/
- /media

Does this mean that sub-folders of ignored folders are *not* ignored?

Thank you

Comment: Did u make sure that USB/Flash/external drive you're trying to write on is working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is because Deja Dup is trying to write to the external backup disk, but can't.  Can you manually create a file on the backup disk in the file manager?

Comment: I can only as root. This seems to be the issue here isn't it?

Comment: Sorry about this newbie error. I am definitely a newbie...